# Helpr finding the z-scores for several rows of numbers that represent different variables?

Tags: z-score

For example, if I had a table that looked like

A. 1 2 3 4

B. 4 3 2 1

C. 2 2 1 3

D. 4 1 1 1

To find the Z score for Row/Variable A, would I use a mean of 2.5 (mean of row A) or a mean of 2.18 (mean of entire set of numbers)?  And the standard deviation of just that row or the entire set of numbers?

Comment: What is your definition of a z-score? Are you using the sample mean and standard deviation or the population mean and SD? // What do you mean by 'the entire set of numbers'? One could argue that all four samples are taken from the population $\{1,2,3,4\}.$ // It is clear that this is a drill problem, but not clear what formula or procedure is the basis of the drill. // Please give some context and show what you have tried.